# Unexpected EOF looking for matching `"'... in line 1. What gives?

Tags: bash, slurm

I am running the following slurm script on a cluster computing system.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=R1.5-CG-nvtrun            # create a short name for your job
#SBATCH --qos=short                   # _quality of service_
#SBATCH --nodes=1                     # node count
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=12          # number of tasks per node
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1             # cpu-cores per task (>1 if multi-threaded tasks)
#SBATCH --mem=10GB                   # total memory requested
##SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=4G              # memory per cpu-core (4G per cpu-core is default)
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1                  # number of gpurs per node
#SBATCH --time=7:00:00                # total run time limit (HH:MM:SS)
#SBATCH --mail-type=all               # send email on job start, end, and fail

# The modules I need to run my job
module purge
module load intel/19.0/64/19.0.5.281    # for running gromacs
module load anaconda3/2020.7
conda activate data-analysis
# run the job

set -e


# keep track of the last executed command
trap 'last_command=$current_command; current_command=$BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG

# echo an error message before exiting
trap 'echo "\"${last_command\" command filed with exit code $?."' EXIT

init=InitializeSystem
em=EnMinimization
nvt=NVT-Equilibration
npt=NPT-Equilibration
md=MolDynamics

for iteration in {1..5}
do 
    echo "iteration number $iteration" 
    echo "setting up editconf..."
    # construct a box using editconf
    gmx editconf -f ./${init}/BZCG.gro -o ./${init}/BZCG-in-box.gro -c -d 1.0 -bt cubic > ./${init}/editconf.txt 2>&1
    echo "executed editconf!" 

    echo "setting up insert molecules..."
    # insert 1000 molecules in a box 
    gmx insert-molecules -box 4.48 4.48 4.48 -ci ./${init}/BZCG-in-box.gro -nmol 600 -o ./${init}/BZCG-setup.gro > ./${init}/insert-molecules1.txt 2>&1 
    echo "executed insert molecules!" 

    echo "setting up grommp for em..."
    # run a minimization script
    gmx grompp -f ./${em}/minim.mdp -c ./${init}/BZCG-setup.gro -p ./${init}/topol.top -o ./${em}/BZCG-EnMinimized > ./${em}/grompp_em.txt 2>&1
    echo "executed grommp em!" 

    echo "setting up mdrun for em..."
    # run the molecular dynamics 
    gmx mdrun -v -deffnm ./${em}/BZCG-EnMinimized > ./${em}/mdrun_em.txt 2>&1 
    echo "executed mdrun for em!" 

    echo "setting up grommp for nvt..."
    # run an NVT script 
    gmx grompp -f ./${nvt}/nvt.mdp -c ./${em}/BZCG-EnMinimized.gro -r ./${em}/BZCG-EnMinimized.gro -p ./${init}/topol.top -o ./${nvt}/BZCG-NVT-Eqbrt.tpr > ./${nvt}/grompp_nvt.txt 2>&1
    echo "executed grommp for nvt!"

    echo "setting up mdrun for nvt..."
    # run the molecular dynamics 
    gmx mdrun -v -deffnm ./${nvt}/BZCG-NVT-Eqbrt > ./${nvt}/mdrun_nvt.txt 2>&1 
    echo "executed mdrun for nvt!"

    echo "moving onto production..." 

    # run the production script 
    echo "setting up grommp for production run..."
    gmx grompp -f ./${md}/md.mdp -c ./${nvt}/BZCG-NVT-Eqbrt.gro -t ./${nvt}/BZCG-NVT-Eqbrt.cpt -p ./${init}/topol.top -o ./${md}/BZCG-MolDynamics.tpr -maxwarn 1 > ./${md}/grompp_production.txt 2>&1
    echo "executed grommp for production run!" 

    echo "setting up mdrun for production run..."
    # run the molecular dynamics 
    gmx mdrun -v -deffnm ./${md}/BZCG-MolDynamics > ./${md}/mdrun_production.txt 2>&1 
    echo "executed production run!" 

    echo "start creating the rdf..."

    gmx rdf -f ./${md}/BZCG-MolDynamics.xtc -s ./${md}/BZCG-MolDynamics.tpr -o rdf_.xvg -selrpos whole_mol_com -seltype whole_mol_com -cut 0 -rmax 2.226 << EOF
    2
    2
EOF

    echo "rdf created!" 

    echo "deleting back-ups..."

    for dir in ${init} ${em} ${nvt} ${npt} ${md}
    do
        rm ./$dir/\#* || true 
    done 

    rm \#* || true
    echo "deleted back-ups!"
    
    # run the analysis, update parameters 
    python update.py
done
```

All the `gmx` stuff I am running is a software bundle called gromacs.

The strange part about this script is that it runs everything as expected, it does the 10 iterations, but once those are done, it outputs an error message saying:
**`` /var/spool/slurmd/job6141167/slurm_script: exit trap: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' ``**

How can there be a mismatched `"` in line 1?

The unindented EOF I have below the

```
2
2
```

seems to be the only way the program does the job i want it to do. If I unindent the EOF there, I get the following error:

```
/var/spool/slurmd/job6141905/slurm_script: line 104: warning: here-document at line 84 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
/var/spool/slurmd/job6141905/slurm_script: line 105: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/var/spool/slurmd/job6141905/slurm_script: exit trap: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

What is the nature of the error here, and how can I fix it?
Any advice you have for me would be appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a `}` in the exit trap line.

Comment: It's line 1 *of the exit trap command*, and the error is misleading; it's actually a missing close brace on `${last_command`.

Comment: Also, run your script through https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing `}` in the line

```
trap 'echo "\"${last_command\" command filed with exit code $?."' EXIT
                            ^
```

It could be what triggers that error.